# Openssl speed - most CPU demanding algorithm

Tags: openssl, benchmarking

I would like to perform quick CPU benchmarks based on `openssl speed`. What would be the most CPU demanding algorithm I could use?

I've already run it either on against algorithms (`openssl speed`), but that takes time, or with DES (`openssl speed  des-cbc`). Is there better option?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Typically key exchange and Diffie-Hellman based algorithms are most taxing to a front-end server or SSL terminator. DES and AES will be fast because they handle the bulk data transfer. They are easier on the server than key exchange.